# Can't Change Root Directory of Site using MSM

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have just gotten MSM installed and now I'm going through the necessary steps to setup the new site on the current server. I've uploaded a new index.php and a new admin.php file to the new directory. If I type in the URL to the admin.php it opens up the Control Panel for the new site. However if I use the URL to the directory of new sites index.php all I get is a white screen. Below are my index.php and admin.php files (I renamed the admin.php file)

```
**index.php**

$system_path = '../../system';

$assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'VOT';
$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://artisanscenterofvirginia.org/VOT/votadmin.php';
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://artisanscenterofvirginia.org/VOT/';

votadmin.php

$system_path = '../../system';

 $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'VOT';
 $assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://artisanscenterofvirginia.org/VOT/votadmin.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered the site url in the Control Panel for your new site?

You will need to got to the new child site in the Control Panel and enter it here: Admin / General Configuration / URL to the root directory of your site

Comment: I have tried adding it to the Control Panel configuration. But every time I hit submit it resets to the current URL. I'm not able to change the URL to anything. Even if I try to delete the URL and hit submit, I don't get an error message or anything, it just resets to the current domain.

Comment: Not sure what your config is but this works for us:

`PARENT: 
admin.php:
assign_to_config[‘site_url’] Commented
assign_to_config[‘cp_url’] Commented

index.php:
assign_to_config[‘site_url’] Commented
assign_to_config[‘cp_url’] Commented

CP PARENT SITE/Admin/General Config/Url to root of site = http://parentdomain 

CHILD:
admin.php:
assign_to_config[‘cp_url’] = ‘http://parentdomain/admin.php’ index.php:
assign_to_config[‘site_url’] = ‘http://childdomain'
assign_to_config[‘cp_url’] = ‘http://parentdomain/admin.php'

CP CHILD SITE/Admin/General Config/Url to root of site = http://parentdomain`

Comment: You might want to straighten that out in a text editor so it's a bit more readable